# Signal order with cascading QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a source model with several cascading `QSortFilterProxyModel` on top.   For my application I would need the `modelReset` signal to bubble up from bottom to top instead of the other way around, how would I do that?

mwe:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
import sys


class Model(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def reset(self):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self.endResetModel()


class Filter(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, model, arg):
        super().__init__(model)
        self.setSourceModel(model)
        model.modelReset.connect(lambda: print(f'Reset {arg}'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    model = Model()
    filter0 = Filter(model, '0')
    filter1 = Filter(filter0, '1')
    filter2 = Filter(filter1, '2')
    filter3 = Filter(filter2, '3')

    button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Reset')
    button.clicked.connect(model.reset)
    button.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

returns:

```
Reset 3
Reset 2
Reset 1
Reset 0
```

but I would like to have

```
Reset 0
Reset 1
Reset 2
Reset 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has an error, instead of monitoring the current model signal you are monitoring the sourceModel, it only changes to:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore


class Model(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def reset(self):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self.endResetModel()


class Filter(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, model, arg, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setSourceModel(model)
        self.modelReset.connect(lambda: print(f'Reset {arg}')) # <---


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    model = Model()
    filter0 = Filter(model, '0')
    filter1 = Filter(filter0, '1')
    filter2 = Filter(filter1, '2')
    filter3 = Filter(filter2, '3')

    button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Reset')
    button.clicked.connect(model.reset)
    button.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

```
Reset 0
Reset 1
Reset 2
Reset 3
```

Comment: @magu_ 
It seemed strange to me that the last one found out first.